# php search multidimensial array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is my array:

```
[60] => Array
    (
        [id] => 122
        [leverancier_id] => 120
        [naam] => 1PK-HP-ELP-KKH-****

        [extra] => array
            (
                 [sku] => 1PK-HP-ELP-KKH-145
            )
    )

[61] => Array
    (
        [id] => 123
        [leverancier_id] => 98
        [naam] => 2PK-HP-ELP-KKH-****

        [extra] => Array
            (
                [sku] => 2PK-HP-ELP-KKH-145
            )
    )
```

And i have to search in the array "extra", if the sku already exists.
If the sku already exists it should return the "id".

I have this function now, but it won't let me search in the array "extra".

```
function hasName($array, $name) {
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if($item["naam"] == $name) return $item['id'];
    }

    return false;
}
```

I can't make this possible in any way, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
foreach($array as $row){
    if(isset($row['extra'])) $id[] = $row['id'];
}
```

The array $id contains ids in which `extra` exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
<?php
$sku = '2PK-HP-ELP-KKH-145';
$arr = Array(
    0=>Array
    (
        'id' => 122,
        'leverancier_id' => 120,
        'weergavenaam' => '1PK-HP-ELP-KKH-****',
        'extra' => array
            (
                 'sku' => '1PK-HP-ELP-KKH-145'
            )
    ),
    1=>Array
    (
        'id' => 123,
        'leverancier_id' => 98,
        'weergavenaam' => '2PK-HP-ELP-KKH-****',
        'extra' => array
            (
                 'sku' => '2PK-HP-ELP-KKH-145'
            )
    ));

   foreach($arr as $row)
   {
       if($row['extra']['sku'] == $sku)
       {
          echo "Id = ".$row['id'];
       }
   }
```

**Output:**

```
Id = 123
```

**Live Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/903358)**

Answer (score 0):

How I understood your question is that you want to return the id if there's a sku (in the extra array), else return false. Maybe this will get you in the right direction:

```
function hasName($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        // if (!empty($item['extra']['sku']) may also work.
        // is_array($item['extra'] may be a little too much in the following line.
        if (array_key_exists('extra', $item) && is_array($item['extra']) && array_key_exists('sku', $item['extra'])) {
            return $item['id'];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```